# Unable to uninstall specific version of pip, Openstack Devstack Install error

Tags: python, openstack, pip

I am getting this error on ./stack.sh  install

[Devstack Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6dIa.png)

When running pip3 --version, I can verify and shows proper version

```
pip 21.1.3 from /opt/stack/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

How do I find this version that ./stack.sh is trying to utilize

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 21.1.3 is available.
```

Most of the docs are about installing pip,  or just running pip uninstall pip,   but when I run that... it finds the 21.1.3  and I am trying to remove 20.2.4

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello. Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139834/python-3-is-not-upgrading-pip-am-i-linking-a-wrong-directory) help?

Comment: unfortunately it only upgrades,  I still have 20.2.4    ---   pip just upgrades parallel and installs additionally 

It does not remove pip 20.2.4      ---  thanks for the link though

Comment: I found it with which pip,   it was under root ~   and the new version was under   stack